# Gulp replace files with minified

Tags: gulp, gulp-minify

I have the following tree structure

```
|-src
|--assets
|---script.js
```

and I want to replace the contents of `script.js` with their minified version of it **WITHOUT** renaming it into `script-min.js`.

The code right now is:

```
gulp.task('minifyjs',['movejs'],function(){
    return gulp.src('src/assets/sample.js',{base:'./'})
        .pipe(gulp_requires.minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/assets/'))
});
```

How should be modified in order to acheive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `gulp-uglify` package instead of minify one.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify